# PHP Random Images with database

Tags: php

I'm using this script for my website to show the random images that are set in the database with ever new setting gamenumbers. set.php is where the database settings are saved.

```
<?php
@include_once('set.php');
$gamenum = fetchinfo("value","info","name","current_game")-1;
    $rs = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `game".$gamenum."` GROUP BY `userid`");
    $i = 0;
    $crd = "";
    while($row = mysql_fetch_array($rs)) {
        $crd .= 'avatar.push(\''.$row["avatar"].'\');';
        $i++;
    }
echo '<script src="js/jquery.easing.1.3.js"></script>
<script>
    $(".stop-game").addClass("hidden");
    function getRandomInt(min, max) {
        return Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min + 1)) + min;
    }
    var avatar=[]; 
    '.$crd.' 
    $( ".hhdgfbd" ).after( "<div id=\"hjgfd\" style=\"width: 1000px;margin: auto;overflow: hidden\"><div id=\"rouletbox\" style=\"height: 140px; width: 100%;  margin: auto\"><div class=\"roulet\"><div class=\"weaponline\" style=\"  margin-left: 330px\"></div><div class=\"mainbox\"><div class=\"weaponbox\" style=\"margin: 5px\"><div class=\"weaponheader\"><center><img style=\"width: 125px; height: 125px\" id=\"img1\"></center></div></div><div class=\"weaponbox\" style=\"margin: 5px\"><div class=\"weaponheader\"><center><img style=\"width: 125px; height: 125px\" id=\"img2\"></center></div></div><div class=\"weaponbox\" style=\"margin: 5px\"><div class=\"weaponheader\"><center><img style=\"width: 125px; height: 125px\" id=\"img3\"></center></div></div><div class=\"weaponbox\" style=\"margin: 5px\"><div class=\"weaponheader\"><center><img style=\"width: 125px; height: 125px\" id=\"img4\"></center></div></div><div class=\"weaponbox\" style=\"margin: 5px\"><div class=\"weaponheader\"><center><img style=\"width: 125px; height: 125px\" id=\"img5\"></center></div></div><div class=\"weaponbox\" style=\"margin: 5px\"><div class=\"weaponheader\"><center><img style=\"width: 125px; height: 125px\" id=\"img6\"></center></div></div><div class=\"weaponbox\" style=\"margin: 5px\"><div class=\"weaponheader\"><center><img style=\"width: 125px; height: 125px\" id=\"img7\"></center></div></div><div class=\"weaponbox\" style=\"margin: 5px\"><div class=\"weaponheader\"><center><img style=\"width: 125px; height: 125px\" id=\"img8\"></center></div></div><div class=\"weaponbox\" style=\"margin: 5px\"><div class=\"weaponheader\"><center><img style=\"width: 125px; height: 125px\" id=\"img9\"></center></div></div><div class=\"weaponbox\" style=\"margin: 5px\"><div class=\"weaponheader\"><center><img style=\"width: 125px; height: 125px\" id=\"img10\"></center></div></div><div class=\"weaponbox\" style=\"margin: 5px\"><div class=\"weaponheader\"><center><img style=\"width: 125px; height: 125px\" id=\"img11\"></center></div></div><div class=\"weaponbox\" style=\"margin: 5px\"><div class=\"weaponheader\"><center><img style=\"width: 125px; height: 125px\" id=\"img12\"></center></div></div><div class=\"weaponbox\" style=\"margin: 5px\"><div class=\"weaponheader\"><center><img style=\"width: 125px; height: 125px\" id=\"img13\"></center></div></div><div class=\"weaponbox\" style=\"margin: 5px\"><div class=\"weaponheader\"><center><img style=\"width: 125px; height: 125px\" id=\"img14\"></center></div></div><div class=\"weaponbox\" style=\"margin: 5px\"><div class=\"weaponheader\"><center><img style=\"width: 125px; height: 125px\" id=\"img15\"></center></div></div><div class=\"weaponbox\" style=\"margin: 5px\"><div class=\"weaponheader\"><center><img style=\"width: 125px; height: 125px\" id=\"img16\"></center></div></div><div class=\"weaponbox\" style=\"margin: 5px\"><div class=\"weaponheader\"><center><img style=\"width: 125px; height: 125px\" id=\"img17\"></center></div></div><div class=\"weaponbox\" style=\"margin: 5px\"><div class=\"weaponheader\"><center><img style=\"width: 125px; height: 125px\" id=\"img18\"></center></div></div><div class=\"weaponbox\" style=\"margin: 5px\"><div class=\"weaponheader\"><center><img style=\"width: 125px; height: 125px\" id=\"img19\"></center></div></div><div class=\"weaponbox\" style=\"margin: 5px\"><div class=\"weaponheader\"><center><img style=\"width: 125px; height: 125px\" id=\"img20\"></center></div></div><div class=\"weaponbox\" style=\"margin: 5px\"><div class=\"weaponheader\"><center><img style=\"width: 125px; height: 125px\" id=\"img21\"></center></div></div><div class=\"weaponbox\" style=\"margin: 5px\"><div class=\"weaponheader\"><center><img style=\"width: 125px; height: 125px\" id=\"img22\"></center></div></div><div class=\"weaponbox\" style=\"margin: 5px\"><div class=\"weaponheader\"><center><img style=\"width: 125px; height: 125px\" id=\"img23\"></center></div></div><div class=\"weaponbox\" style=\"margin: 5px\"><div class=\"weaponheader\"><center><img style=\"width: 125px; height: 125px\" id=\"img24\"></center></div></div><div class=\"weaponbox\" style=\"margin: 5px\"><div class=\"weaponheader\"><center><img style=\"width: 125px; height: 125px\" id=\"img25\"></center></div></div><div class=\"weaponbox\" style=\"margin: 5px\"><div class=\"weaponheader\"><center><img style=\"width: 125px; height: 125px\" id=\"img26\"></center></div></div><div class=\"weaponbox\" style=\"margin: 5px\"><div class=\"weaponheader\"><center><img style=\"width: 125px; height: 125px\" id=\"img27\"></center></div></div><div class=\"weaponbox\" style=\"margin: 5px\"><div class=\"weaponheader\"><center><img style=\"width: 125px; height: 125px\" id=\"img28\"></center></div></div><div class=\"weaponbox\" style=\"margin: 5px\"><div class=\"weaponheader\"><center><img style=\"width: 125px; height: 125px\" id=\"img29\"></center></div></div><div class=\"weaponbox\" style=\"margin: 5px\"><div class=\"weaponheader\"><center><img style=\"width: 125px; height: 125px\" id=\"img30\"></center></div></div><div class=\"weaponbox\" style=\"margin: 5px\"><div class=\"weaponheader\"><center><img style=\"width: 125px; height: 125px\" id=\"img31\"></center></div></div><div class=\"weaponbox\" style=\"margin: 5px\"><div class=\"weaponheader\"><center><img style=\"width: 125px; height: 125px\" id=\"img32\"></center></div></div><div class=\"weaponbox\" style=\"margin: 5px\"><div class=\"weaponheader\"><center><img style=\"width: 125px; height: 125px\" id=\"img33\"></center></div></div><div class=\"weaponbox\" style=\"margin: 5px\"><div class=\"weaponheader\"><center><img style=\"width: 125px; height: 125px\" id=\"img34\"></center></div></div></div></div></div></div>");
    for(var i=1; i <= 34; i++) {
        var rand = getRandomInt(0,(avatar.length-1));
        $(\'#img\'+i).attr("src",avatar[rand]); 
        //alert(avatar[rand]);
    }';

$winner = fetchinfo("userid","games","id",$gamenum);
$avatar = fetchinfo("avatar","users","steamid",$winner);
echo '$(\'#img30\').attr("src","'.$avatar.'");'; 
echo '$(\'.mainbox\').css("margin-left",getRandomInt(-425,-5)+"px");
    setTimeout(function() {
        $(".mainbox").animate({marginLeft: getRandomInt(-3715,-3590)+"px"}, 7000, "easeOutExpo");
        audioElement3.play();
    },50);
    setTimeout(function() {
        $("#hjgfd").remove();
        roulet = 0;
    },10000);
</script>';
?>
```

But everytimes it displays the images of the gamenumber before. I tried different things but i couldn't find a solution.

Comment: So is the problem that the random images are only from the game before, but you want it from any game? The SQL query seems to only select from the previous game: `game".$gamenum."`

Comment: I want that the random images are from the current game, not that before.

Comment: It selects the latest game# from the database but i think its because of the

Comment: $gamenum = fetchinfo("value","info","name","current_game")-1;

Comment: So if you remove the -1 does it work? `$gamenum = fetchinfo("value","info","name","current_game");`

Comment: Nope, If I remove that, it's the current pot, but the winner is not shown. The images of all others are shown but the winner image is missing.

Answer (score 0):

You could simplify a lot of your fetch/string building code. It's totally redundant, and also vulnerable to the JS equivalent of sql injection attacks.

```
$crd = array();
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($rs)) {
    $crd[] = $row['avatar'];
}
... blah blah blah
var avatar = <?php echo json_encode($crd); ?>;
```

Now you're directly creating the string representation of an array, without wasting cpu cycles building up the array one-item-at-a-time with push() operations, and you also eliminate the possibility of these `avatar` values causing a JS syntax error, if they're something OTHER than numbers.